# NetworkX detecting serial nodes

Tags: python, networkx

given a directed graph in networkx with serial nodes, branches and loops. There are some nodes that are described as so called "key-nodes". A "key" node is just a node with an attribute "key". Start node is the one that is most left (sorry I forgot to mark it).

I need to identify all "set of nodes" with the following properties:

- at least three serial nodes (no upper limit)
- Key nodes are excluded for that process (red node in that example)

[image]

My idea:

1. Identify possible "start nodes"
2. Check if 3 serial

The idea behind: If there are 3 serial nodes, I can simply the network by splitting the middle node in the successor/predecessor.

The result should look like the following:

[image]

But I am not sure, how to implement that in python / networkX.

Would be great, if someone could help me.  Thank you very much

Comment: Are "serial node" and "key node" your own terms? There's no mention in [the networkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest).

Comment: If yes, define "key node", "serial node" and "start node" as you haven't yet.

Comment: Hey: i updated the question --> thank you for your hints

Comment: Please also give identifiers to the entities on your picture for us to be able to refer to them.

Comment: Do not hesitate to mention what task you're trying to solve. That's because your current groupings look rather arbitrary, I cannot see any system (and thus a suitable formal definition) for the groups.

Comment: Are you able to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit the question to define what a "serial" node is.

Comment: The question is little open-ended. Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Do you know in advance which nodes are "key" or "start" nodes ?